# Can someone help? Sending notifications to all users or some users in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I want to send a single notification message to multiple users or all users. I have tried many to many fields but the sent to id won't save the i.d's of the users that i have sent the message to.

***Models.py***

```
class Notifications(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sent_to = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
    message = models.TextField(null=True)
    message_reply = models.TextField(null=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

***Views.py***

```
def add_notification(request):

    notifs = Notifications.objects.all()
    users = CustomUser.objects.filter(is_staff=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddNotifForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.message_reply = "none"
            instance.save()
            sent_to = form.cleaned_data.get('sent_to')
            messages.success(request, f'Message has been successfully sent .')
            return redirect('add_notif')
    else:
        form = AddNotifForm()

    context={

        'notifs' : notifs,
        'form' : form,
        'users' : users,
    }

    template_name ='main-admin/add-notif.html'
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

***Forms.py***

```
class AddNotifForm(forms.ModelForm):

    sent_to = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=CustomUser.objects.filter(is_staff=True).exclude(is_superuser=True),
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            required=True)

    class Meta: 
        model = Notifications
        fields = ['sent_to', 'message']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> every time you save a form using commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

So you'll have to call `save_m2m()` after `instance.save()` if you are using `commit=False`:

```py
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.message_reply = "none"
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m() # <-- Add this
```

Comment: This worked for me and thank you for the tip

Comment: But now how can I call the notifications for each user in a datatable since it's not set on notification model?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean, but you can get all the users from the notification object like: `sent_to_users = notification.sent_to.all()`. Otherwise it might be better to write a new question for it

Comment: I'd get an error 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all', if i use that notifications.sent_to.all()

Comment: It will only work for one instance of notification (the result of `get`, `first`, `last`, etc.). So for example: `n = Notification.objects.first(); n.sent_to.all()`

Comment: I see, so i cannot show in a table all of the notification for that user based on their i.d?

Comment: You can, by using: `Notification.objects.filter(sent_to=request.user)`

Comment: I tried this and it does not show the notification even if there is an entry in the notifications_sent_to table referring to the logged in user

Comment: I just tried it out and it works. Are you able to share the code you used to try this out in your other question? Also please show the id of the logged in user, as well as the entry in the `notifications_sent_to` table

Comment: Wait ill post the codes again